Terrible performance while performing IO operations on system drive
I'm having very poor performance on newly installed windows 11 with basic IO operations using explorer.
This happens when I'm copying archive from other solid drive to my m.2 where my fresh system stored. The graph is ugly sinusoid from 500MiB to 0 and, when it shows zero, my whole system freezing for a few seconds. Discord totally mutes itself on that period and folders opening with some delay. Only cursor works perfectly smooth.
I've thied to switch the opponents. I made same thing, but with hard drive and that solid drive. It worked amazingly! I had perfect line with ~500MiB speed without any lags.
I think this happens because the OS trying to work with it's binary files or smh, and m.2 starting "throttling". I'm aware that this will blow my legs when I'll be working with some programs stored on this m.2 and cause performance issue.
So, can there be good solution? Should I move my programs to another drive to prevent future self-blowing? Or there is nasty command that I should to put into regedit? Or it's just hardware issue with my m.2?
My specs:
Ryzen 5 5600X
16 GB DDR4 2666GHz

WD Green SATA SSD 2280 (240Gb) << os and programs on m.2
Samsung SSD 870 QVO (1Tb) << ssd with steam games on sata
WD Blue 3.5" (1Tb) << hdd file garbage

Edit: I have indexing. Could it be the issue?

The indexing hypotheses passes the plausibility test, at least, so it can't be outright falsified. That said, even with indexing running that shouldn't be a problem, other than slightly less performance/speed, and certainly not with known good solid state drives. Now, your question lacks information about the actual drives' technology, something that more likely than not matters to understand the problem. Namely, it seems you make a distinction between "solid drive" and M.2 and this needs clarification: M.2 is just a connector type and it supports different types of drives, (...)

(cont...) but ALL are "solid state drives". M.2 can be fitted with NVMe (newer and more prevalent) or SATA SSDs. If what you have in the M.2 slot is a SATA drive and you have other SATA drives using the typical connectors of old, you may well be experiencing the failure/flakiness of a shared SATA controller. Hard to imagine that happening, in any circumstance, with a NVMe drive.

So, as expected, both are SATA drives and likely sharing the same SATA controller and, perhaps, lanes. The reason then it isn't happening when doing the same but from or to the HDD might be because either the other drive is managed by a different controller, using different lanes or just due to the HDD speed limits the copy operation never reaches the problematic threshold. I have no answer as such because there are too many factors at play here. Next comment will give suggestions only:

Suggestions: 1. Update UEFI; 2. Check the drive(s) in UEFI settings and makes sure it's AHCI (preferable, same performance, less headaches); if some motherboard's "RAID" make sure the required drivers are installed in Windows and update from the chipset manufacturer, if available.

Thanks for you help  I can tell that they are using different controllers on my motherboard. When i tried to disable all of my drives, I had two options in UEFI: APU Bus Enable and SATA Bus Enable. Disabling first - disables my m.2 sata ssd; Disabling SATA - disables other drives connected to sata

So, this is 100% not software issue? It's just something bad with my motherboard or m.2?

In all likelihood yes, something not quite right with the motherboard, but it may not be a (physical) hardware issue, just a soft (firmware) one, that may or may not be solved by a UEFI update.

Also. I updated UEFI few months ago and I'm already using AHCI. Also RAID mode disabled

Does it happen whenever the OS drive is involved (i.e. to and from said drive)? Does copying to or from the other drives shows the same problem?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The drive itself may benefit from a firmware update: https://support-en.wd.com/app/answers/detailweb/a_id/51127/initiator/user

The dashboard says that I have up-to-date drivers somehow. I don't remember that I updated them for two years. I've made a screenshot of copying archive from other ssd to system one. The issue happened when MiB is falling >> https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1102571046860754995/1237460225099960351/image.png?ex=663bba24&is=663a68a4&hm=80086d34f7d17a809679e4985762a3ca864f8a1870b04524a7415edcbc636a29&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=1084&height=488
